# can not travel int Extjs treestore

Tags: extjs

I have treestore, i want to traverse the each node. I found no `each` function in the treestore. But the store have the each function. I also tried the treestore.data. but not success.
pls help me .tks!

Comment: Why you need to travel the tree nodes.... what are you trying to achieve... Please specify clear question to help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ext.data.TreeStore` has no `each` method, since it deals with `Ext.data.Tree`. However, [Ext.data.NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) has `eachChild` method, you can use this method to traverse the tree.

```
function traverse(node) {
    // do something with node

    node.eachChild(function(child) {
        traverse(child); // handle the child recursively
    });
}

traverse(yourTreeStore.getRootNode()); // start tree traversal with root node
```

Comment: I'm looking for a faster implementation of grid.expandAll() so I'm trying grid.getRootNode.eachChild(function(){})  but is still slow ... any faster way of iterating childs of the root node ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ext.each as bellow:

```
Ext.each(tree.getRootNode().childNodes, function (node) {
        console.log(node.data.text);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use Ext.Array.each for your requirement....
Refer below sample example.

```
Ext.Array.each(records, function(record, index, records) {
      if(!(record.get('name')==='')){
      }
});
```